# How to hide information on graph from the Legend in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tidyverse, data-visualization

I have horizontal dots plot replotted via ggplotly

```
df <- data.frame (origin = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),
              Percentage = c(23,16,32,71,3,60,15,21,44,60),
              rate = c(10,12,20,200,-25,12,13,90,-105,23),
              change = c(10,12,-5,12,6,8,0.5,-2,5,-2)

library(ggplot2)

plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x = rate, y = factor(origin, rev(origin)))) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = origin), color = 'gray') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2, color = 'gray') +
  geom_point(aes(color = 'Rate'), size = 10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = rate), color = 'white') +
  geom_point(aes(x = change, color = 'Change'), size = 10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = change, x = change)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = ~paste0(.x, '%'), name = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#aac7c4', '#5f9299')) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = 'gray50')) +
  labs(color = NULL, y = NULL)

ggplotly(plt)
```

[image]

The only issue is that when I hide one of the dot from the figure, texts are still appeared (see below), so is there way to tackle this issue and hide text with circle by clicking on legend?

P.S
(setting text colour in white color = 'white' is not option for me)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fill aesthetic for the points (as long as they are shape = 21) and use the color aesthetic for the text. As long as these have the same labels for aesthetic mapping, the interactivity for both points and text will be linked.

One minor annoyance is that this changes the plotly legend labels, even though they are correct in the ggplot version. This requires a little direct manipulation of the plotly object itself:

```r
plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x = rate, y = factor(origin, rev(origin)))) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -100, xend = 200,
                   y = origin, yend = origin), color = 'gray') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2, color = 'gray') +
  geom_point(aes(fill = 'Rate'), shape = 21, size = 10, color = NA) +
  geom_text(aes(label = rate, color = 'Rate')) +
  geom_point(aes(x = change, fill = 'Change'), 
             color = NA, shape = 21, size = 10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = change, x = change, color = "Change")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = ~paste0(.x, '%'), name = NULL) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#aac7c4', '#5f9299')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "white")) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = 'gray50')) +
  labs(color = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL)

p <- ggplotly(plt)

p$x$data[[3]]$name <- p$x$data[[3]]$legendgroup <-
  p$x$data[[4]]$name <- p$x$data[[4]]$legendgroup <- "Rate"
p$x$data[[5]]$name <- p$x$data[[5]]$legendgroup <-
  p$x$data[[6]]$name <- p$x$data[[6]]$legendgroup <- "Change"

p
```

This gives us the following plot:

[image]

Now clicking on Rate we get:

[image]

And clicking on Change we get

[image]

Comment: is it possible to add horizontal lines for every category? I tried geom_hline(yintercept = c(1:as.numeric(length(df$origin))), linetype = 1, color = 'gray') but next legend does not work well

Comment: @user4567794374545 sure - plotly can be a bit funny about plotting lines with infinite co-ordinates in a way that doesn't bother ggplot. You can get round this by using `geom_segment` instead. See my update.